# Issue with ListDensityPlot when using logarithmic scale

Tags: graphics, plotting

I have got some frequency response data from a speaker measured with different incident angles between speaker and microphone taken in an anechoic chamber. The data can be found [here](http://www.file-upload.net/download-7510499/SaschaData.zip.html).

The whole experiment consists of measurement series at 5 different angles which are `{0°, 30°, 60°, 90°, 180°}`

[image: plot of measurement series]

I individually import (and save them in a variable) with:

```
 importlist[path_] := 
 ToExpression @ Partition[Flatten @ Drop[Import[path, "Words"] , 2], 2]
```

and process them (downsampling and rearranging) with the following functions to get a list suitable for `ListDensityPlot`

```
downsampleFunction[list_, n_, pos_] := 
Downsample[pos @ Transpose @ list, n]

combineFunction[list_, angle_, downsampleBy_] := 
Thread[{downsampleFunction[list, downsampleBy, First], angle, 
downsampleFunction[list, downsampleBy, Last] }] 

listcombineFunction[listoflists_, listofangles_, downsampleBy_] := 
Flatten[Table[
combineFunction[listoflists[[i]], listofangles[[i]], 
downsampleBy ], {i, 1, Length@listoflists}], 1]
```

If now plotted with something like

```
ListDensityPlot[
listcombineFunction[
{list0FR, list30FR, list60FR, list90FR, list180FR}, 
{0°, 30°, 60°, 90°, 180°}, 1000]]
```

I get a nice looking plot but in linear scale. Since this is frequency response data (and I would like to show that directivity is a matter that becomes (more) relevant at higher frequencies) I would rather prefer a logarithmic frequency (horizontal) axis.

If I change my processing functions by adding a `Log10@` in front of my frequency range data like done here:

```
combineFunction2[list_, angle_, downsampleBy_] := 
Thread[{Log10 @ downsampleFunction[list, downsampleBy, First], angle, 
downsampleFunction[list, downsampleBy, Last] }] 

listcombineFunction2[listoflists_, listofangles_, downsampleBy_] := 
Flatten[Table[
combineFunction2[listoflists[[i]], listofangles[[i]], 
downsampleBy ], {i, 1, Length@listoflists}], 1]
```

and plot the results I get a ugly graphics glitch (I guess some interpolation issue due to the accelerated changes forced by the logarithm?). An example with corrected ticks and different styling options:

[image: example image]

P.S.: I noticed another glitch concerning the 45° rotated frame labels. Does anybody know a fix for the behaviour? If I try the same code with another example the font looks somewhat thinner but not as aliased as in the sample picture above. Example for "desired" behaviour:

```
 LogLinearPlot[Log10[x], {x, 1, 1000}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Flatten[
 Table[{d 10^e, Rotate[d 10^e, 45 Degree]}, {e, Floor[Log[10, 35]],
 Ceiling[Log[10, 22000]]}, {d, 1, 5, 1}], 1], Automatic}, 
 Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 600]
```

Comment: FileNuke is annoying me.  What do I have to click to start the actual download?

Comment: 1-click-hoster aren't what they were used to be anymore... until I find another one that actually works you can try https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/74966785/SaschaData.zip

Comment: Added another download link that hopefully does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Adding `ClippingStyle -> Automatic` as option to ListDensityPlot fixes the issue -  as simple as that -  don't know why I didn't see that before. Still leaves the strangely aliased font when turning the frame ticks at an 45° angle. I found out that when exporting the cell as .eps the font looks "normal" (just a bit thinner) in third party software (at least in Indesign).