# Tick frequency (monthly to quarterly ) on DateListPlot

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time

Probably a mundane question, but I am stuck. I have a time series of monthly observations, where the dates are specified as follows.

```
date = With[{first = DateObject[{2011, 1, 1}, "Day"]}, DateRange[first, 
DatePlus[first, {{93, "Month"}, {-1, "Day"}}], {1, "Month"}]];
```

I am trying to plot the graph but have the quarterly, not monthly, dates appear on the X axis. For presentation reasons, I might need to reduce the frequency to semi-annual. This is what I get from my command.

```
DateListPlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{1, -0.5}, {93}]], {2011, 1}, FrameTicks -> 
{Automatic, {date, None}}, DateTicksFormat -> {"Month", "/", "Year"}]
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
DateListPlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{1, -0.5}, {93}]], {2011, 1},
 FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {date[[;; ;; 6]], None}}, 
 DateTicksFormat -> {"Month", "/", "Year"}, ImageSize -> 700]
```

[image]

Thanks to Mr. Wizard:

[How to rotate TickMarks in DateListPlot?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8378/how-to-rotate-tickmarks-in-datelistplot)

```
DateListPlot[Accumulate[RandomReal[{1, -0.5}, {93}]], {2011, 1},
  FrameTicks -> {Automatic, {date[[;; ;; 3]], None}}, 
  DateTicksFormat -> {"Month", "/", "Year"}, 
  ImagePadding -> 40, 
  ImageSize -> 700] /. 
    x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> (x /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 45 Degree])
```

[image]

Comment: It gives error, does it work also with 12?

Comment: this works : https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23948/issue-with-listdensityplot-when-using-logarithmic-scale/24007#24007